# "tinymce.init is not a function" when trying to browserify tinymce

Tags: jquery, npm, tinymce, browserify

I can't get a basic tinymce call to work in browserify, even though it works perfectly if I just load tinymce from a CDN. Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do.

```
// main.js
var tinymceConverter = require('./modules/tinymce-converter');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    tinymceConverter.init();
}

// tinymce-converter.js
'use strict';

var tinymce = require('tinymce/tinymce');

module.exports = {
    init: function () {
        tinymce.init({
            // some params
        });
    }
};
```

However, I get the `Uncaught TypeError: tinymce.init is not a function` error from the js console.

I have tried various combinations of other `require` calls, some in combination with jQuery, which is used a lot in this project. (Hence a solution with jQuery would be welcome, although my first priority is to get it working at all.) Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution or did you just end up sticking with loading it from the CDN?

Comment: I would have loved to post a solution but I'm afraid I never found any and eventually resorted to loading from CDN. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

I got around it by adding setup attribute, then the console warned that I didn't have some plugins code and image, once I added those it stopped giving console errors and I was able to take out the setup attribute.

`tinymce.init({
    selector: '#tiny',
    plugins: ['paste', 'link', 'code', 'image'],
    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.on("init", function (ed) {
            alert(7);
        })
    }
});`